# Confusion regarding the summation used in the equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fourier-series, classical-mechanics

I have an equation where there is a single summation on both sides of the equation.

In the image provided taken from the article [A], they did some simplification which I am unable to understand.

They used the result of 19 and substituted in the 16 to get equation 20.

My question is what happened to the summation on both sides?
[image]

---

[A] L.A. Bergman, J.K. Hall, G.G.G. Lueschen, D.M. McFarland: "Dynamic Green's functions for Levy plates", *J. Sound Vib.*  **162**-2 (1993), 281-310. [doi:10.1006/jsvi.1993.1119](https://doi.org/10.1006/jsvi.1993.1119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, let $(16)$ be of the form of

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin(n\pi x)=\delta(x-\xi)\delta(y-\eta)$$

and $(19)$ is of the form of

$$\delta(x-\xi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n \sin (n\pi x)$$

After they subsitute $(19)$ into $(16)$, since

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin(n\pi x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\delta(y-\eta)\sin(n\pi x)$$

Hence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty( a_n - C_n \delta(y-\eta)) \sin(n\pi x)=0$$

Hence the LHS is the fourier series of the zero function, hence

$$a_n = C_n \delta(y-\eta)$$

Comment: Is it possible to briefly explain the last line  of your answer. My understanding of  linearly independence means one function cannot be expressed by other function or set of function.

Comment: If we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin(n\pi x)=0$ then LHS is the fourier series of the zero functions and we know that $b_n=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped  me in understanding things properly